# Проблемы с выводом списка имен баз данных в zabbix

Tags: json, sql-server, powershell, zabbix

Нужно передать имена баз данных MSSQL в zabbix. Передать нужно в формате JSON. Но скрипт после выполнения почему то еще передает и значение количества баз. Не в переменную $basename, а просто выводит в консоли. И из-за этого zabbix ругается что формат JSON неверен. Подскажите, можно ли избежать вывода значения количества баз?

```
#Задаем переменные для подключение к MSSQL  
$SQLServer = "myServer"

$uid = "Login" 

$pwd = "Password"

#Создаем подключение к MSSQL
$connectionString = "Server = $SQLServer; User ID = $uid; Password = $pwd;"
$connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$connection.ConnectionString = $connectionString
$connection.Open()

#Создаем запрос уже непосредственно к MSSQL
$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand  
$SqlCmd.CommandText = "SELECT name FROM  sysdatabases"
$SqlCmd.Connection = $Connection
$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd
$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
$Connection.Close()

#Получили список баз, записали в переменную.
$basename = $DataSet.Tables[0]

write-host "{" 
write-host " `"data`":[`n"

foreach ($name in $basename) 
    {  
        $line= "{ `"{#DBNAME}`" : `"" + $name.name + "`" },"
        write-host $line  
    }

write-host
write-host " ]"
write-host "}"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После некоторых экспериментов выяснилось, что добавление `set nocount on` в начало команды не помогало, в консоль всё равно выводилось число строк, возвращаемых запросом.

Однако оказалось возможным подавить вывод числа строк в консоль, перенаправив вывод в `$null` во время выполнения команды, т.е. заменив

```
$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
```

на

```
$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet) > $null
```

Comment: Спасибо! Заработало.